Kubernetes Ingress deployment performance improvement question
If I deploy an instance of my nginx ingress to every node of my Kubernetes cluster, will that improve overall response time?
My line of thought is: my cluster has 10 user-nodes, and only 3 replicas of the nginx so there's a big probability that the destination pod will NOT be on the same node as any of the ingress controllers

If you're using a LoadBalancer type Service to reach the ingress controller, it will land on a random node, and when Nginx calls the backend, again it will go to a random replica.  It's very likely the request will cross nodes.  This is pretty typical behavior, and I wouldn't try to optimize it unless something like distributed tracing highlights it as a bottleneck.  (And even then I'd work with your local network administrator rather than trying to tweak code in cases like this one.)

Indeed it will reduce the latency and helps to improve the response time but the main drawback is that the resource consumption will increase and network complexity also will increase since you want to deploy in every node. If resource management is not an issue for you then you can try deploying the ingress controller as a daemon set as well.
